# Redirect from http to https using Angular and Apache not working

Tags: apache, angular, redirect, https, routes

I have an SSL cert installed and I'd like to redirect all traffic from http to https. I've added this section to my Apache server:

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.memoriesgameseries.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.memoriesgameseries.com/"
</VirtualHost>
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.memoriesgameseries.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/memoriesgameseries_com.crt"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/httpd/memoriesgameseries_com.ca-bundle"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/memoriesgameseries.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

As per the Apache documentation. My Angular routing file looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MemoriesComponent }  from '../memories/memories.component';
import { TearsComponent }  from '../tears/tears.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'memories', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'memories', component: MemoriesComponent },
  { path: 'tears', component: TearsComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class RoutingModule {};
```

However, whenever I attempt to access the website via http, instead of correctly redirecting, when I type in a root address, such as `www.memoriesgameseries.com` and `http://memoriesgameseries` the redirect fails to kick in at all. When I type in a URL above the root domain, such as `http://memoriesgameseries.com/memories` the redirect kicks in and I see the https URL in the browser (e.g. `https://www.memoriesgameseries.com/memories`), but I get a:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /memories was not found on this server.

Response from the server. What's likely to be causing this issue?

Comment: I have also tried `Redirect permanent / https://www.memoriesgameseries.com/` which results in a too many redirects error in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that server are trying to manage 404. That's no life, let SPA do that for you.

When 404 redirect to index.html

```
  RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code causes a violation: `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: script-src 'self' [etc]`

Comment: I forgot to mention to add this into .htaccess file in root of your server folder.

Comment: I'm on Fedora, so it uses `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` instead of `.htaccess`. I added the suggested code to the `httpd.conf` file, which resulted in the Content Security Policy violation error.